# Android Intent with String

Tags: android, android-intent

I made a Listview Edittext to search items. And now I want to bring up the Activity.

```
// When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
```

Under this sentence, there are some intent codes. But I do not want to call it that way. I want to use

```
nosun.add("A");
nosun.add("B");
nosun.add("C");
```

this things (A,B,...) that I would bring intent. So the purpose is that without entering the code of each string in the list, I want to get connected with the activities of such A_Activity or B_Activity with take that things.

And this is my code.

```
package com.example.code;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Example extends Activity {

 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = null;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.example);

  //Generate list View from ArrayList
  displayListView();

 } 

 private void displayListView() {

  //Array list of countries
  List<String> nosun = new ArrayList<String>();
  nosun.add("A");
  nosun.add("B");
  nosun.add("C");


  //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array

  dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.listview, nosun);
  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

  // Assign adapter to ListView

  listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

  //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView

  listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {

    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text

    Intent intent=new Intent(Example.this, Another_Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    //Fin

   }
  });

  EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
  myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
  }
  });
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass objects as well. so the best way is to make a class and pass it as follows

```
 intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);
```

Also:

Pass the necessary data in the Intent, use **startActivityForResult()** to start the second Activity,

Comment: sorry but can you explain more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Send the data to intent like this,

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Example.this, Another_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("listdata", nosun);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get those details into other activity is,

```
List<String> myList = (List<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listdata");
```

Comment: It's maybe my misunderstanding, but send data between activities is not I want to do. I want to start activity with listitems. On example, when I click A item, then A_Activity is started, and when I click item B, then B_Activity is started. I want to do like this.